# event if only one div has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have lots of divlayers with the class named ".current". depending on what the user does some of remove the class and some will get it again. this works fine, but what i want to is fire an event if only one div layer has the class ".current". how can i detect if only one element has the class current?
for example

```
if ($('#div4').hasClass('.current')) {
    alert("fire me something");
}
```

something like "is the only one" hasClass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your event callback, simply check the number of divs that have the `current` class:

```
if ($('#div4').hasClass('current') && $('div.current').length === 1) {
    ...do stuff...
}
```

If you're only ever using `current` on `div`s, then you could just use `$('.current').length === 1`.

Comment: im using different divs with the same class. but if one div is the only one who has the class "current" i want to fire something with that div.

my code with your help is:

   `var $('#div6') = $sixBG

   if($sixBG.hasClass("current").length === 1) 
    {
  console.log("something"); }`

but it doesnt fire! i check it with console, its the only one who has inview but nothing happens! what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You merged the code wrong, you want to check that `$sixBG.hasClass('current')` AND `$('div.current').length === 1`, which means you need to use a logical and operator.

Comment: can you explain it with a sample. sorry, these questions maybe seem stupid to you, but im a beginner and have to learn it!

Comment: i already updated my answer to show the usage of the "and" operator (`&&`)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use the css class as the selector and then get the length:

```
if($(".current").length == 1 ) {
   alert('fire me something');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://api.jquery.com/size/ or http://api.jquery.com/length/

```
$(".current").length
$(".current").size()   *deprecated as of v1.8
```

Either will give you the count.  Anytime you adjust the class check to see the count and fire the action if its 1

Answer (score 0):

I "think" you could do:

```
if($('.current').length == 1) { //DO }
```

I believe the selector will return an array of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have error syntaxe! you should add an ")" for your condition. and dont use the calss selecotr (".") . that's will work:

```
if($('#div4').hasClass('current')){
        alert("fire me something");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could see how many instances of the class .current that there are by using length. e.g.

```
var mycount = $(".current").length;
alert(mycount);
```

Then do whatever you like with the result.